# SAS Proc SQL INTO - Cannot write a macroed variable into macro?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

```
data COLUMN_LIST_DATA;
length COLUMN_LIST CATEGORY $8.; 
input COLUMN_LIST CATEGORY;
datalines;
COL1 MY_COLS
COL2 OTHER
COL3 MY_COLS
COL4 OTHER
COL5 OTHER
;
run;
```

```
%macro TBL_Keep(var); %macro _; %mend _;

        PROC SQL NOPRINT;
            *Create SELECT statement for columns we want;
            SELECT COLUMN_LIST INTO: &var. SEPARATED BY ' '
            FROM COLUMN_LIST_DATA
            WHERE CATEGORY = "&var."
            ;
        QUIT;
%mend;

%TBL_Keep(MY_COLS);
%put &MY_COLS.;
```

Not sure why the above code doesn't work.... Does INTO not accept macroed variables as input?
If I write the same code, manually substituting the macroed "&var." with "MY_COLS" it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem is that **if the macro variable named MY_COLS does not already exist before the call to `%TBL_KEEP()` then the macro variable will be LOCAL and disappear when the macro execution ends**.

You could just set it to some default value before calling the macro to insure it exists.

```
%let my_cols=BEFORE THE CALL;
%TBL_Keep(MY_COLS);
%put &=my_cols;
```

Or make the macro smart enough to force the macro variable to exist by issuing a %GLOBAL statement.  While changing the macro definition you should also fix the second issue: **If no observations match the WHERE condition on the query then the macro variable's value will not be changed.**

```
%macro TBL_Keep(var); 
%if not %symexist(&var) %then %global &var;
%let &var= ;
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
SELECT COLUMN_LIST
  INTO :&var. SEPARATED BY ' '
  FROM COLUMN_LIST_DATA
  WHERE CATEGORY = "&var."
;
QUIT;
%mend TBL_Keep;
```